# Continuous Clash with Database Handle and Null

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli

I feel like I'm missing something about OOP in PHP.  I've read a number of tutorials on connecting to mysql but keep running into errors that tell me my database handle is non-existent, even though it does connect.  I have the following code, and everything is connecting correctly, but when I attempt to close the connection (I'm aware PHP closes the connection when the script finishes, but this is also a learning exercise for me) with $connection->close(); I get a notice that $database_handle is undefined and as a result the mysqli_close($database_handle) is referencing a NULL variable and returns a fatal error.

Why does $connection->connect(); work and $connection->close(); return a fatal error?

The classes:

```
<?php

class database_connection  {
    var $hostname = 'localhost';
    var $username = 'root';
    var $password = '';
    var $database = 'assistant';
    var $database_handle;

    function connect() 
    {
        $database_handle = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        if (!$database_handle) 
        {
            die('Could not connect to database!');
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->database_handle = $database_handle;
            echo 'Connection established!';
        }
        return $this->database_handle;
    }

    function close() 
    {
        mysqli_close($database_handle);
        echo 'Connection closed!';
    }

}

?>
```

the referencing page.php:

```
<?php

include 'includes/database_classes.php';

$connection = new database_connection();
$connection->connect();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM  `users`';
$result = mysqli_query($connection->database_handle, $query);

if($numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result)) 
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo $numrows;
    echo "<br>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $database_username = $row['user_name'];
        $database_password = $row['user_password'];
        echo $database_username;
        echo $database_password;
    }
}

$connection->close();   

?>
```

Comment: Because you already closed the connection in `page.php`

Comment: Connections normally dont need closing, they close themselves at end of script execution

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? var for a varibale definition has not been used for at least a couple of major releases of PHP

Comment: Hi Riggs - where specifically does it close?  I understand what you're saying, because if the connection is closed the database handle would be null, but where specifically does it close before I call $connection->close(); ?

Comment: I'm using php 7.  I was actually thinking these should be protected but I was cutting corners so I could get the general understanding first, and var was the first thing I thought of just to get it going.

Comment: Ahh I see the error `mysqli_close($this->database_handle);` as `$database_handle` does not exist in that method

Comment: Beautiful, it worked!  Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I suggest you adopt this approach so that you only every have one connection at a time on a script

Also this fixes your error from

```
function close() 
{
    mysqli_close($database_handle); // $database_handle does not exist
    echo 'Connection closed!';
}
```

to

```
function close() 
{
    mysqli_close($this->database_handle);
    echo 'Connection closed!';
}
```

And this makes sure even if you call the `database_connect()` method more than once in a script, it only ever creates one connection

```
<?php

class database_connection  {
    private $hostname = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'assistant';
    private $database_handle = NULL;

    function connect() 
    {
        if ( ! isset($this->database_handle) ) {
            // only create a connection if one does not already exist
            $this->database_handle = mysqli_connect($this->hostname,
                                                    $this->username, 
                                                    $this->password, 
                                                    $this->database
                                                   );

            if (!$this->database_handle) {
                die('Could not connect to database!');
            } 
        }    

        return $this->database_handle;
    }

    function close() 
    {
        mysqli_close($this->database_handle);
        echo 'Connection closed!';
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Wondering why the other answers; given [you were asked by the OP to do so...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007171/continuous-clash-with-database-handle-and-null#comment75042926_44007171) *Hmm........*

Comment: Thanks again, Riggs, for looking into it.  I'm still getting the hang of OOP in PHP and your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Also thanks for the additional info.  I'll be looking more deeply into this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
function close() 
{
    mysqli_close($this->database_handle);
    echo 'Connection closed!';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a few scoping problems and you're not using the parameters correct everywhere. Please try the below and let me know if it helps.

```
<?php

class database_connection  {
    var $hostname = 'localhost';
    var $username = 'root';
    var $password = '';
    var $database = 'assistant';
    var $database_handle;

    function connect() 
    {
        $this->database_handle = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        if (!$this->database_handle) 
        {
            die('Could not connect to database!');
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'Connection established!';
            return $this->database_handle;
        }
    }

    function close($database_handle) 
    {
        mysqli_close($database_handle);
        echo 'Connection closed!';
    }
}
?>


<?php

include 'includes/database_classes.php';

$connection = new database_connection();
$connection->connect();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM  `users`';
$result = mysqli_query($connection->database_handle, $query);

if($numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result)) 
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo $numrows;
    echo "<br>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $database_username = $row['user_name'];
        $database_password = $row['user_password'];
        echo $database_username;
        echo $database_password;
    }
}

$connection->close($connection);   

?>
```